# What is the python alternative for C#'s custom property setters?

Tags: python, oop, setter

I'm coming from C# world into python. In C#, I can use `get` and `set` to make updates to other object properties upon setting a value to a property, something like this:

```
private int _age;
private string _description;

public int Age
{
    set
    {
        _age = value;
        _description = (_age < 1500) ? "new": "old";
    }
}
```

In python, I have the following class definition:

```
class Record(object):
    age = 0
    description = ""
    <...a bunch of other properties...>
```

How can I set the `description` property of a `Record` object when I set the `age` property, in the same way as I can do it in C#, without having to write custom functions like `get_age(self):` and `set_age(self):`?

Comment: By using @property https://pythonguide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/property.html#managing-attributes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the `property` decorator for this:

```py
class Record:
    def __init__(self):
        self._age = 0
        self._description = ""
        
    @property
    def age(self):
        return self._age

    @age.setter
    def age(self, value):
        self._age = value
        self._description = "new" if value < 1500 else "old"

    @property
    def description(self):
        return self._description

rec = Record()
print(rec.age, rec.description)
rec.age = 1000
print(rec.age, rec.description)
rec.age = 2000
print(rec.age, rec.description)
```

output:

```
0 
1000 new
2000 old
```

When you use `@property`, every time you use `rec.description`, you are actually calling `rec.description()` and the return value of that call is used as the attributes value. This value gets recalculated every time you use the attribute.

If there was only the `@property` decorator, it would be impossible to set the attribute, as there is only a function that calculates the value. Luckily, we can use `@age.setter`. Every time the attribute is set (`rec.age = value`), this function is called.

We can use of this to make the `description` attribute also being set when the `age` attribute is set.

If you want to learn more about decorators, [this page](https://realpython.com/primer-on-python-decorators/) is a good start.

Another, less recommended, way to do this is using `__setattr__`:

```py
class Record:
    def __init__(self):
        self.age = 0
        self.description = ""
        
    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        super().__setattr__(key, value)
        if key == "age":
            self.description = "new" if value < 1500 else "old"

rec = Record()
print(rec.age, rec.description)
rec.age = 1000
print(rec.age, rec.description)
rec.age = 2000
print(rec.age, rec.description)
```

The output is exactly the same.

Every time we set an attribute on an instance by using  `instance.attrname = attrvalue`, python calls `instance.__setattr__("attrname", attrvalue)`. Usually, this is the `__setattr__` function which is inherited from `object`, the class from which every class inherits.

But when we override this function, we can choose our own behavior. In this case, it means that we also set the `description` attribute when the attribute 's name is `"age"`.

But, of course, we should still call the `object`'s `__setattr__` function to make that the attribute is actually set. We could do this directly using `object.__setattr__(self, key, value)`, but a better way to do this is using [`super`](https://realpython.com/python-super/). `super()` allows us to call functions of the class from which there is inherited. In this case it's `object`, but if you later on decide to let `Record` inherit from another class that also defines `__setattr__`, that class's `__setattr__` will be called.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. No need to recalculate `description` every time you want to read it.

Answer (score 1):

One Pythonic way to do it is using property decorator, which creates a method that works like attribute:

```
class Record:
    def __init__(self, age):
        self.age = age
    
    @property
    def description(self):
        return "new" if self.age < 1500 else "old"
    
print(Record(age = 1600).description) # old
```

With this approach, `description` is not stored in memory but instead it's recalculated every time you access it.

Another way would be with full suite of getter and setter decorators, but it requires creating additional methods you wanted to avoid:

```
class Record:
    def __init__(self, age):
        self.description = None
        self.age = age
    
    @property
    def age(self):
        return self._age

    @age.setter
    def age(self, value):
        self.description = "new" if value < 1500 else "old"
        self._age = value
    
print(Record(age = 1600).description)
```

This way `description` is stored in the object, and will get updated every time you set value to `self.age`.

Answer (score -2):

Decorators let you use a setter and a getter for your class

```
class Record:
    def __init__(self, age):
        self.age = age
        self.description = age

    # using property decorator
    # a getter function
    @property
    def description(self):
        print("getter method called")
        return self._description
    
    # a setter function
    @description.setter
    def description(self, age):
        if(age < 1500):
            self._description = "new"
        else:
            self._description = "old"
```

Comment: This isn't how you'd use setters with the given example. With your code you'd have to do `self.description = 1600` to get `"old"`.

Comment: No, it is set when you instantiate the class as I made it need the age in the init.

Comment: But it desyncs as soon as you modify `age` attribute of the object. If you change `age`, `description` will still refer to old value.